# Why do thoughts take a non-zero length of time?

Tags: thought

I was staring blankly at my desk thinking about how to overcome a programming task at work when it suddenly dawned on me I had spent the best part of half an hour trying to envision how this problem could be solved. This got me thinking, why is it thoughts have to take a non-zero length of time to occur? What is the process in the mind that causes it to be slow, almost as if I were to be speaking the thoughts aloud? Is our thought process just wildly inefficient?

Comment: This seems like an awkwardly conceptualized question to me because it appears you are equating nonzero length of time with slow.  Why would you expect a thought process or series of thoughts to take no time?

Comment: According to a popular theory in cognitive psychology called Dual Process Theory, there are at least 2 systems or types of "thinking" - fast and slow.  Fast thinking does happen nearly instantaneously - arguably the vast majority of decision-making that one does in a day uses this system.  You may be asking about slow thinking, in which case I would recommend adjusting the question accordingly.

Comment: There are other ways to think, some of which are strikingly fast, compared to what you are describing. The term "noetic" or "noesis" describes this fast, high processing capacity thinking